# Prove that the set of lines in the plane is equal in cardinality to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**My attempt:**

I begin by trying to find a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\gamma=\{$the set of lines in the plane$\}$. I think the set $\mathbb A = \{ \{(a,-b),(-c,d) \} | \forall a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} \}$ would give me all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I also know that every $x \in \gamma$ is defined by a slope and point. Then there would exists $f$: $\mathbb A \to \gamma$ such that $$f(\mathbb A)=\left ( \dfrac{-b-d}{a+c},(a,-b) \right )$$

The order of the slope and the point obviously do not matter. I am just trying to show that $f$ maps to a point, and slope which uniquely determines each $x \in \gamma$.

If this is correct then $\gamma \equiv_c \mathbb{R}^2 \equiv_c \mathbb{R}$

I see that there are easier ways but is there anything strikingly incorrect about my attempt?

Comment: Using slope-intercept form for the lines would probably be easier.

Comment: How do you define a vertical line by a slope and a point?

Comment: Let $A$ be the set of lines that pass through the origin. Clearly, there is a bijection between $A$ and $[0,\pi)$ (map each line to the angle that defines it), therefore also between $A$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Let $B$ be the set of lines in the plane. Clearly, there is a bijection between $B$ and $A\times\mathbb{R}$ (map each line to the pair $(\ell,d)$, where $\ell$ is the line through the origin that is parallel to the original line and $d$ is the distance between the two lines. Therefore, there is a bijection between $B$ and $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who says the lines have to be staight or even represent a function in the form y = f(x) ?

Suppose that a line is instead defined parametrically where x = x(t) and y = y(t) and we require that x(t) and y(t) are continuous functions of the real variable t.

Let X be the set of all such functions {x(t)} and similarly Y = {y(t)}. If L is the set of possible lines then the cardinality |L| = |X x Y|

But X = Y = C the set of continuous functions of a real variable, and |L| = |C x C|

As a general result, for any set S we have |S x S| = S, so |L| = |C| and the only question is then what is |C|.

A particularly neat result is that a continuous function is compeltely specified by its values at rational points, so that it is equivalent to the set of continuous functions on Q -> Q.

The continuous functions on Q are a subset of all functions Q -> Q, i.e. each continuous function is a subset of Q x Q, so that C is a subset of P(Q x Q) and consequently |C| <= |P(Q x Q)| = |P(Q)| = |R|. I.e |L| <= |R|

It's also easy to see that we can inject R into L by a function f(x) = (x, 1) so that |R| <= |L|

Putting that together (Cantor Bernstein theorem) then |L| = |R| and there is a bijection between them.

Comment: [Lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_%28geometry%29) are straight.